# IPMI console redirect (KVM) via java applet causes multiple keystrokes

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, dell, console, ipmi

I'm using a dell c6100 and can connect to the web based IPMI management tool, and I can get console redirection running via the java applet.

But many keystrokes (especially enter) generate 2 or more keystrokes to the server. This is making installations almost impossible as it quickly skips past many steps.

Anyone experienced the same? Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar situation. I used a MACRO feature on the KVM console to login to the system because when I typed in root it printed as `rroooootttt`.

Comment: What exactly was your setup and solution? As it stands, your answer isn't very helpful.